# HR Employee Count with Slicing by Dimensions - Slowly Changing Dimension

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to **calculate headcount while keeping the measure sliceable by any dimension** connected to the fact table. Given the nature of my tables and model, what I need to do is a point in time calculation on a Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2.

**I managed to make it work using the function KEEPFITLERS, but I need a more scalable function that wouldn't require me to list all the dimensions I want to slice by.**

Here is my PowerBI file with sample data: https://gofile.io/d/smS2Hr

Here is a simplified sketch (image) of my model: https://ibb.co/fQYpsdx

[image: Model]

**Background:**

The first measure I am calculating is the number of Employees at the Start of the Period (Employees SoP). If the end-user selects in PowerBI the whole month of January 2020, the Start of the Period is Jan 1st, 2020. Hence, "Employees SoP" for the month of Jan 2020 will give the number of employees on Jan 1st, 2020.

The formula below calculates the correct values for Employees SoP:

```
Employees SoP =
VAR MinDate = MIN ( 'Date'[Date]) //Mininum date selected by end-user in PowerBI
VAR Result =
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact[EmployeeId]),
FILTER(ALL('Fact'), 'Fact'[EffectiveStartDate] <= MinDate
&& IF(ISBLANK('Fact'[EffectiveEndDate]), date(2050,1,1), Fact[EffectiveEndDate]) > MinDate
))
RETURN
Result
```

The problem with the formula above is that, because of the ALL function, the measure is not sliceable by any dimension, i.e., Pay Class and Employment Status (the same number repeats itself).

Results:

[image: Employees SoP]

Hence, I created this other measure using KEEPFILTERS, and it works perfectly.

```
Employees SoP KEEPFITLERS =
VAR MinDate = MIN ( 'Date'[Date]) //Mininum date selected by end-user in PowerBI
VAR Result =
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact[EmployeeId]),
FILTER(ALL('Fact'), 'Fact'[EffectiveStartDate] <= MinDate
&& IF(ISBLANK('Fact'[EffectiveEndDate]), date(2050,1,1), Fact[EffectiveEndDate]) > MinDate
), KEEPFILTERS(PayClass), KEEPFILTERS(EmploymentStatus))
RETURN
Result
```

[image: Employees SoP KEEPFILTERS]

The problem with this formula is that I have to list all the dimensions I want to slice by ( e.g., PayClass, EmploymentStatus) inside the DAX formula. This is not very scalable.

I did some experimenting with REMOVEFILTERS but it looks like it does not work with DirectQuery for now, so it wouldn't solve my production problem. Link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax

**QUESTION:
How can I write this measure using an alternative to KEEPFILTERS with which I wouldn't have to list each dimension I want to slice by?**

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - I'm unclear about your statement "what I need to do is a point in time calculation on a Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2" as none of the Dimensions (as shown) are SCD2: they don't have start and end dates, for example.
Can you have more than one record per employee in the fact table? If you can then what is the grain of the fact table and what are you actually measuring?

Comment: Just as an aside, it's often easier to populate "end dates" with a date far in the future e.g. 3000-12-31, when they are unknown rather than leaving them blank; this allows you to do, for example "date_value between start_date and end_date" rather than having to worry about nulls/blanks

Comment: Hi @NickW ! I will have to calculate measures that use both effectivestart and effectiveend later. For now, in the sake of simplification, my example contains only the Employees at Start os Period that uses only the effectivestart  date. You can see the grain of the table and data for the fact and dimension tables in the PowerBI file whose link is in the first few paragraphs of the question ( https://gofile.io/d/smS2Hr)

Comment: @NickW Sure, we can add a future date, but the sample data in this example mimics what I get in the production environment, and the production file already has blanks, so I handle it by setting a future date in the measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to solve my problem. I made both relationships to the Dates table "inactive". With that, I could remove the "ALL" function in the DAX formula and now it not only calculates the correct values, but it also slices nicely. I will have to use the USERELATIONSHIP function to calculate more complex measures but, in most of the cases, this simple solution works like a charm.

[image]

```
Employees SoP without ALL = 
VAR MinDate = MIN ( 'Date'[Date]) //Mininum date selected by end-user in PowerBI
VAR Result =
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact[EmployeeId]),
FILTER('Fact', 'Fact'[EffectiveStartDate] <= MinDate
            && IF(ISBLANK('Fact'[EffectiveEndDate]), date(2050,1,1), Fact[EffectiveEndDate]) > MinDate
            ))
RETURN
Result
```